# Modulo Problem, Fermat's little theorem

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Find the value of the unique integer x satisfying $O \le x \le 17$ for which
**$$
4^{1024000000002} \equiv x\pmod{17}
$$**
*I think this is related to Fermat's little theorem. I'm knowledgeable with the Chinese remainder theorem and just need some advice on solving this*.

Comment: So what's the remainder of $1024000000002$ modulo $17-1$?

Comment: recent edit added an x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use Fermat's little theorem. Since 17 is prime and 4 is relatively prime to 17, we know that $a^{17-1}=a^{16}\equiv 1\pmod{17}$. Now since
$$
1024000000002 = 16\cdot64000000000+2
$$
we'll have
$$
4^{1024000000002}=4^{16\cdot64000000000+2}=(4^{16})^{64000000000}(4^2)\equiv(1)(16)\pmod{17}
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $4^2=16\equiv-1\pmod {17}$  and $a\equiv b\pmod m\implies a^n\equiv b^n\pmod m$ for integer $n\ge0,$

$4^{1024000000002}=(4^2)^{512000000001}\equiv(-1)^{512000000001}\pmod{17}\equiv-1\equiv16$

Comment: recent edit added an x

Comment: @matthiasgh, edited the answer:)

Comment: thanks m8 I think i understand what your saying so i keep getting the square and removing the mod until i reduce the LHS

Comment: @matthiasgh, if you have understood correctly, we need only one squaring and as  $512000000001$ is odd, $(-1)^{512000000001}=-1$

Comment: Ok thanks I just did the example $3^{3002} \cong x(mod.13)$ and got the answer 1 is this correct

Comment: @matthiasgh. Since $3^3=27\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ we'll have $3^{3002}=3^{3\cdot 1000 + 2}=(3^3)^{1000}\cdot 3^2\equiv 1\cdot 3^2\pmod{13}$

Comment: whats the value of x

Comment: $x$ will be $3^2$.

Comment: @matthiasgh, in most of cases, the method I mentioned is worth trying before using Fermat's Little Theorem as gives $4^{16}\equiv1\pmod {17}$ or $3^{12}\equiv1\pmod{12}$ whereas my method gives you $4^2\equiv-1\pmod {17}$ or $3^3\equiv1\pmod{27}$. Try $4^{16a+12}\pmod{17}$  or$3^{12b+11}\pmod{13}$